# Not working yet im trying to resize the Bitmap/s but they are still 1920X1080 why?

Tags: c#

This is the code:

```
if (Form1.ExtractAutomatic == true)
            {
                using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(_width, _height, _width * 3, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, pBuffer))
                {
                    if (!this.Secondpass)
                    {
                        long[] HistogramValues = Form1.GetHistogram(bitmap);
                        Form1.Histograms.Add(HistogramValues);
                        long t = Form1.GetTopLumAmount(HistogramValues, 1000);
                        Form1.averagesTest.Add(t);

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        if (_frameId > 0)
                        {
                            double t = Form1.averagesTest[_frameId] / 1000.0 - Form1.averagesTest[_frameId - 1] / 1000.0;
                            w.WriteLine("averagesTest >>>  " + t);
                            double tt = framesCounts();
                            if (_frameId == framesCounts())
                            {
                                w.Close();
                            }
                            if (Form1.averagesTest[_frameId] / 1000.0 - Form1.averagesTest[_frameId - 1] / 1000.0 > 0.0) 
                            {
                                count = 6;
                            }

                            if (count > 0)
                            {
                                ResizeBitmap(bitmap, 10, 10);
                                bitmap.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipX);
                                bitmap.Save(Path.Combine(_outFolder, _frameId.ToString("D6") + ".bmp"),ImageFormat.Bmp);
                                count --;
                            }
```

And ResizeBitmap is:

```
public static Bitmap ResizeBitmap(Bitmap b, int nWidth, int nHeight)
        {
            Bitmap result = new Bitmap(nWidth, nHeight);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)result))
                g.DrawImage(b, 0, 0, nWidth, nHeight);
            return result;
        }
```

Why the files on the hard disk are 1920X1080 and not 10X10 ? 
And why the saving is so slow ? I thought saving files to the hard disk in this case about 2600 frames should be fast no ?

Can someone show me how ot fix it according to my code ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
bitmap = ResizeBitmap(bitmap, 10, 10);
```

You aren't assigning the resized bitmap to anything.

Comment: I cant make bitmap = The problem is im getting error if im trying to assign the variable bitmap since its a using variable. using(var bitmap ... cant be assigned thats the error im getting when doing bitmap = ResizedBitmap(bitmap,10,10);

Comment: The bitmap can't be assigned back to the same variable. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148840/how-can-i-change-the-size-of-a-bitmap-in-its-using-block

Comment: You can assign it to a new bitmap variable if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The method returns the bitmap, so you need to use the return value of the method:

```
Bitmap newBitmap = ResizeBitmap(bitmap, 10, 10);
```

Still the same answer as here: [How do i resize the Bitmap in this function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143511/how-do-i-resize-the-bitmap-in-this-function)

Comment: Guffa the first question in the link was in Form1 while this time its in another class where bitmap is a use variable. In Form1 bitmap wasn't a use variable.

Comment: @user1741587: It's still exactly the same problem. The bitmap that you send into the method isn't changed. The method returns a new bitmap, which is the resized image that you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Use this near the bottom of your first code sample:

```
using (Bitmap resized_bmp = ResizeBitmap(bitmap, 10, 10))
{
    resized_bmp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipX);
    resized_bmp.Save(Path.Combine(_outFolder, _frameId.ToString("D6") + ".bmp"),ImageFormat.Bmp);
    count --;
}
```

This uses a new `Bitmap` variable (and disposes it properly) in order to perform the save, as Tim suggested.